# Accessing an element attribute to delete

Tags: javascript, function, dom, addeventlistener, queryselector

I'm trying to write a To-Do app. But I am stuck on deleting the li element. I have started to code, but I couldn't make it. The idea is; First reaching the `element.offsetHeight` because I thought even though the elements name and their class are the same their offsetHeight is different. So I thought I could delete it. But the problem is that I can't find the right if statement my goal is to reach this:

If the elements offsetHeight is equal to the clicked element (element itself) then remove the element.

I also have this question: How to reach and clicked elements I can't do it because the spans have the same class

NOTE: The span inside the li needs to be used with an event listener. I mean the function will trigger when we clicked the span.

```js
const X = document.querySelectorAll(".span")
console.log(X)

for (let i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
  let element = X[i]
  if (element.offsetHeight == element.offsetHeight)
    console.log("a")
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: slategray;
}

.graywrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fcfff7;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.add-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #21A0A0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid slategray;
  input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFE900;
}

.added-section {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #046865;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062);
  opacity: .6;
  backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #023f3d;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #035c59;
  padding-left: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062);
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.span:hover {
  border: slategray;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: slategray;
}
```

```html
<div class="graywrap">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="add-section">
      <input id="inputText" type="text" placeholder="Add an item">
      <button id="addİtem" class="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="added-section">
      <ul id="list">
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>



      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="clear-all">Clear All</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use the `element.offsetHeight` to determine which element the user has clicked on. The [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) contains all the information you will need.

By using the `MouseEvent#currentTarget` property you will have access to the `<span/>` element. Then by using `element#parentNode` you will have access to the parent `<li />` element.

```js
const X = document.querySelectorAll(".span")

for (let i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
  let element = X[i]
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const parentListItem = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    if (parentListItem) parentListItem.remove();
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: slategray;
}

.graywrap {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fcfff7;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.add-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #21A0A0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid slategray;
  input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFE900;
}

.added-section {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #046865;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062);
  opacity: .6;
  backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #023f3d;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #035c59;
  padding-left: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.062);
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.span:hover {
  border: slategray;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: slategray;
}
```

```html
<div class="graywrap">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="add-section">
      <input id="inputText" type="text" placeholder="Add an item">
      <button id="addİtem" class="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="added-section">
      <ul id="list">
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>
        <li class="list-item">DKDSKDK <span class="span">X</span></li>



      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="clear-all">Clear All</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: My question is can you do it with offsetHeight. Also what does function(event) means?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".span");
spans.forEach(span => {
    span.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        span.parentElement.remove();
    });
})
```

which will add a handler to each item with the class "span" which will remove its parent.

Answer (score 0):

first of all,I suggest you use different text for DKDSKDK  like

```
<li class="list-item">DKDSKDK 1<span class="span">X</span></li>
<li class="list-item">DKDSKDK 2<span class="span">X</span></li>
<li class="list-item">DKDSKDK 3<span class="span">X</span></li>
```

this will help make sure that the correct task item was deleted .

Second,offset height will get you the height of the element and from what I can see all 3 of them have offsetheight of 20.

finally,you just need to add an event listener on the span to delete it's parent :

```
    const X = document.querySelectorAll(".span")
    // console.log(X)
for (let i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    let element = X[i];
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
        // this.parentElement.remove();     this refers  to the span
        element.parentElement.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: can you explain how does de system knows that the span im clicking is the one that needs to be deleted. İ have the idea that if i click one X then all the spans will be deleted. since they all have the same class

Comment: in javascript,each html element is represented in something called DOM "Document Object model" think of it as if all the HTML tags were part of Tree.using Dom you could know which elements are next to each others,have the same parent or you could know the parent of any ement .in your case the DOM knows that your span is a child of  li "DOM know that this particular span belongs to this particular li"

Comment: so when you grab the the first span -->element  ,Dom knows this is the span and when when you use element.parent (span.parent) it will take you to the li that has this span (the first li.  remove() will delete this element()li along side all it's children (span)